# Using a function that returns a promise, inside a then() block

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have a promise chain as follows :

```
return performTaskA().
then(performTaskB).
then(performTaskC).
then(performTaskD).
then(performTaskE);
```

`performTaskD` is as follows :

```
function performTaskD() {
    Model.something().
    then(function(result) { 
         something something with result; //BREAKPOINT 1
    }); 
}
```

When I run the promise chain above, BREAKPOINT 1 never gets hit and the control proceeds to `performTaskE`.
However, when I call the function `performTaskD()` separately, BREAKPOINT 1 does get hit. What am I doing wrong in the case of the promise chain?

If I return the promise in `performTaskD`, I still have the same issue. The only difference is that the control never proceeds to `performTaskE` and the process exits.

For clarity, `performTaskD` is as follows :

```
AccountModel.findById(acctId).
    then(function (account) {
        destAccount = account; //destAccount is a var declared in the outer scope.
});
```

Comment: You shoud `return` the promise from `performTaskD` so that it gets chained properly

Comment: Show us what `Model.something` does. Apparently it has a problem with running after the other tasks. Also, have you tried adding an error handler?

Comment: @Bergi Model.something is just a mongoose method which return the result of a `find()` using a promise.

Comment: @Bergi Also added a .catch(). It never gets hit.

Comment: In that case, it sounds like a mongoose bug. But have you also set a breakpoint at `Model.something()` and ensured that it actually gets called? Maybe one of the previous promises in the chain did not fulfill.

Comment: yes I have a breakpoint set at Model.something() and it does get called.

Answer (score 3):

`return` the `Promise`s

```
function performTaskD() {
    return Model.something().
    then(function(result) { 
         return something something with result; //BREAKPOINT 1
    }); 
}
```

Comment: If I return the promise in performTaskD, I still have the same issue. The only difference is that the control never proceeds to performTaskE and the process exits.

Comment: Would suggest including `.catch()` at end of chain as well, to determine what issue is.

Comment: I did. the .catch() never gets hit

Comment: What is "something something with result"?

Comment: assigns a variable in the outer block to result. `x = result;` where x is a var declared in the enclosing function.

Comment: That is not a clear description of what is occurring within `.then()` chained to `Model.something()` at `performTaskD()`. Can you include the full text of "something something with result" at Question?

Comment: Edited my question with the full text you asked for.

Comment: The same principle applies as described at Answer, `return` `destAccount` from `.then()`

Comment: What is logged at `.catch()`? Where is `AcctId` defined? or, is `AcctId` `result` passed to `.findById()`?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Mongoose documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html) `Model.find(something)` does not return a promise. You need to call `Model.find(something).exec()`. The `performTaskD` should be something like:

```
function performTaskD(AcctId) {
  return AccountModel.findById(AcctId).exec().
  then(function (account) {
    destAccount = account;
    return account;
  });
}
```

Comment: It does return a thenable when you don't pass a callback, which is enough.

Comment: @Bergi yes, but you can't chain thenables. You need an actual promise

Comment: …a thenable whose `.then` method returns a promise. It should work out of the box, the only thing that is missing are the other methods from `Promise.prototype`.

Answer (score 0):

"then" function is called when a promise is resolved. In your task functions, you handle the promise inside the function itself, so the rest of the chain's "then" doesnt gets called.

[Use Promise.resolve](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve)

```
function performTaskD() {
   return Model.something().
   then(function(result) {             
        something something with result; //BREAKPOINT 1
        Promise.resolve(result)
   }); 
}
```